# Running a URL shortening website

Tags: halal-haram, internet

I have a website that allows users to shorten their links. They can shorten the URL of any website, which could be, for instance, a phishing attack page (page to steal users' credentials) or a pornographic website for that matter. For clarification, the short links generated in my website redirect to users' original links.

Could the entirety of this service be haram because of those minority of malicious user-generated links?

P.S. it's a renowned service, and widely used for many purposes like marketing to track campaigns...

Comment: Like @YoussefNassim said. It’s up to the user for whether they’ll use it for good or bad, not you.

Comment: Isn't it like making a tool with which a user can do good or harm, like a TV, knife etc..And those aren't haram to sell, wa Allah Aalam.

Comment: The thing that bothers me with the above analogy is that the merchant sells the knife once and that's it, of course regardless of what the buyer would use it for, but it's a sold product, the seller lost ownership. In my case, my website keeps redirecting to wherever users want, I keep providing the service, no ownership transfer happens...I'm sorry for the scrutiny but I can't help it  , especially that I've seen it used for spamming people on the internet